# JavaScript validate, then print and submit

Tags: javascript, printing, form-submit

I have a submit function to validate form inputs, then optionally (checkbox) print as part of the submit process.

The problem is that when printed, form submission never completes, without printing form submission works correctly.

```
<INPUT class=checkboxes id="Place order" onclick="return checkfields()" type=submit value=SUBMIT name="Place order">
```

The validation always works correctly (AFAIK).

```
function checkfields() {
    var missinginfo="Please fill the following information";

    var bres = true, qty=0, elem;

    var tqty = document.getElementById('bottles').value;
    if (tqty ==0){alert("No wine selected");bres=false;return bres;}
    if (tqty %6 !=0){
        alert("Orders need to be in 6 bottle packs please add " + (6 -(tqty %6)) + " Bottles to order");
        bres=false;
        return bres;
    }   //end if
    for (i=1; i<30; i++) {
        elem = document.getElementById('f'+i);
        if(elem !=null){
            if(elem.value== ""){   // || 
                //(document.form.website.value.indexOf("http://") == -1) || 
                //(document.form.website.value.indexOf(".") == -1)) {
                bres = false; missinginfo += "\n    " + (document.getElementById('f'+i).name);
            }     //end if
        }     //end if
    }     //end for
    if(!bres){alert (missinginfo );}

    // end of validation here, print if checkbox checked
    if(bres && document.getElementById('cprint').checked==true){window.print();}

    document.getElementById('doc').value = "";
    return bres;
}    //end function
```

Any suggestions on how to remedy, or am I doing something completely wrong?

Comment: If I put an Alert() after the print() the form submits correctly, could this be a timing or focus issue?

Answer (score 1):

Use `onsubmit` instead of `onclick`:

```
<INPUT class="checkboxes" id="Place order"
    onsubmit="return checkfields();"
    type="submit" value="SUBMIT" name="Place order">
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, with onsubmit, no validation or printing happens